# Need solution regarding a scenario in magento 2

Tags: magento2

We produces tea in 1kg,3kg and 5kg. But for smaller vendor we sell it like 35g,80g and have some other variations. Tea is a raw material and we sell finished product. So we sell using tin,bag and label so that customer get a finished product. On front-end we want customer to buy only tea and not to worry about tin,bag or label. But in back-end he is buying basically 3 product. 1)tea 2) tin/bag 3) label

I want to manage inventory of each product(tea,tin/bag,label) also.

Can you let me know best scenario to do with magento 2. I would appreciate.